# Properly cancelling a Socket.XXXAsync call

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networking

Im working on a Task-based wrapper around SocketAsyncEventArgs for a personal project. Ive got everything working so far, except Task Cancellation. In implementing it, ive run into a problem in the form of lack-of-understanding as to how to implement the cancellation in the correct manner.

Say that i have Task-returning ReceiveAsync and ReceiveFromAsync methods which take a CancellationToken with the following signatures:

```cs
public Task<int> ReceiveAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    cancellationToken.Register(state => {
        // do something to cancel the operation when the cancellationToken is signalled
    }, someState);

    bool completedAsync = socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
    // ...
}

public Task<int> ReceiveFromAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    cancellationToken.Register(state => {
        // do something to cancel the operation when the cancellationToken is signalled
    }, someState);

    bool completedAsync = socket.ReceiveFromAsync(e);
    // ...
}
```

Furthermore, say that i have SendAsync and SendToAsync methods, also with a CancellationToken with the following signatures:

```cs
public Task<int> SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    cancellationToken.Register(state => {
        // do something to cancel the operation when the cancellationToken is signalled
    }, someState);

    bool completedAsync = socket.SendAsync(e);
    // ...
}

public Task<int> SendToAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    cancellationToken.Register(state => {
        // do something to cancel the operation when the cancellationToken is signalled
    }, someState);

    bool completedAsync = socket.SendToAsync(e);
    // ...
}
```

The SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed event handler looks like so. Assume a correct implementation of the SocketAsyncEventArgs handlers thus far. The only thing missing is cancellation:

```cs
public void HandleIoCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args) {
    switch (args.LastOperation) {
        case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
            switch (args.SocketError) {
                    case SocketError.Success:
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case SocketError.OperationAborted:
                        Debug.WriteLine("CompleteReceive experienced SocketError.OperationAborted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        // ...
                        break;
            }

            break;

        case SocketAsyncOperation.ReceiveFrom:
            switch (args.SocketError) {
                    case SocketError.Success:
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case SocketError.OperationAborted:
                        Debug.WriteLine("CompleteReceiveFrom experienced SocketError.OperationAborted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        // ...
                        break;
            }

            break;

        case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
            switch (args.SocketError) {
                    case SocketError.Success:
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case SocketError.OperationAborted:
                        Debug.WriteLine("CompleteSend experienced SocketError.OperationAborted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        // ...
                        break;
            }

            break;

        case SocketAsyncOperation.SendTo:
            switch (args.SocketError) {
                    case SocketError.Success:
                        // ...
                        break;
                    case SocketError.OperationAborted:
                        Debug.WriteLine("CompleteSendTo experienced SocketError.OperationAborted!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        // ...
                        break;
            }

            break;

        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(HandleIoCompleted)} doesn't support {args.LastOperation}");
    }
}
```

From looking at other questions on this topic, i have read that to cancel the Socket.ReceiveAsync or Socket.ReceiveFromAsnc operation i need to dispose of the underlying socket. This would however interfere with any asynchronous send operations that were in-flight, which would end with a SocketError.OperationAborted when the socket was disposed. Likewise, cancelling any Socket.SendAsync or Socket.SendToAsync operations would interfere with currently in-flight receive operations, which would also experience a SocketError.OperationAborted when the socket was disposed.

What is the correct way of cancelling the operation in a safe manner, so that UDP and TCP traffic can resume after a packet is lost (where without cancellation the receiveFromAsync and receiveAsync call would never call e.Completed)?

If additional code is required, just add a comment saying as much and i will flesh out the code as best i can.

Comment: 1) Move to Microsoft's SocketTaskExtensions if cancellation is not that urgent for you. That saves you from using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`. 2) Migrate to pipelines, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines and then cancellation control is much easier.

Comment: @LexLi the whole point of this project was to use SocketAsyncEventArgs, and i set out to do it as a challenge to myself. Whilst i could chicken out and go for the easier option, im not going to do that here, seeing as how ive already implemented the rest of my goals (those being efficient sending and efficient receiving of data).

Answer (score 0):

## Using `Task.WaitAsync`

I had a problem with properly cancelling `await listener.AcceptAsync()`. When I closed the listener it threw an exception and the socket was not properly released. I found a valid solution that uses a two-step task initialization, maybe it will help others in a similar situation and it is applicable to any `Socket.xxxAsync()` method:

```cs
//just for testing: the cancellation will occur after 2000 milliseconds
using var cst = new CancellationSourceToken(2000); 

try
{
    //listener is your Socket instance
    var handlerTask = listener.AcceptAsync();
    var handler = await handlerTask.WaitAsync(cst.Token);

    //then you can do the same with the handler
    while (true)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[1024];
        var receiverTask = handler.ReceiveAsync(bytes);
        var bytesCount = await receiverTask.WaitAsync(cst.Token);
        //then process the data batch before receiving the next one
        if (your_end_of_msg_predicate())
            break;
    }
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    //The cancellation token causes `e` to contain a TaskCanceledException
}
```

The exceptions thrown can vary in be different setups. In my case (described below) it is an `AggregateException` but I suppoe it could also be directly the `TaskCanceledException`.

#### Little side note

Since I have all this inside of a `Parallel.Invoke` along with other methods and I need all of them to be completed before the computation goes on, I ended up switching `await` for `.Result` to avoid calling the invoked method with `async`:

```cs
var handler = handlerTask.WaitAsync(cst.Token).Result;
//and a few lines later
var bytesCount = receiverTask.WaitAsync(cst.Token).Result;
```